# Can't get respond from server when app is in background - iOS4

Tags: iphone

I know that Apple supported application running in background mode, what I want to do is sending http request to get data from server then give user some notifications and I want repeat this action during several time using timmer. I'm using XCode-3.2.4 and Iphone4.1 simulator, it dose support background running, but when I made http request to my server, the responding function wasn't called. Anyone can help me how to do this ??? please. 
Code like this :

```
    - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application{
 UIApplication*    app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

 bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
     [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
     bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
 }];
 // Start the long-running task and return immediately.
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
  // Do the work associated with the task.

  responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];  
  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.unpossible.com/misc/lucky_numbers.json"]];
  [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    });
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
 [responseData setLength:0];
 NSLog(@"%@",@"Server responded");
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
 [responseData appendData:data];
 NSLog(@"%@",@"Server transfered data");
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
 NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connection failed: %@", [error description]]);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {  
 [connection release];
 NSLog(@"%@",@"Server transfered data");
 UIApplication*    app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
 [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
 bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do a synchronous request instead. Seems you are limited to one thread in the background.

```
NSURLResponse *response;
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
```